# How do I choose the signs and angles when converting the equation of a straight line from general form to normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra

The general form of a straight line is $ Ax + By + C = 0 $. One way to convert this into the normal form ($ x \cos \omega + y \sin \omega = p $) is to find out $ \cos \omega $ , $ \sin \omega$ and p individually using the formulae:
$$ \cos \omega = \pm \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}} $$
$$ \sin \omega = \pm \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}} $$ and
$$ p = \pm \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}} $$

My question is, once you have these expressions, how do you choose which signs to use in the equation? For example, $ x \cos 30^0 + y \cos 30^0 = 5$ is not the same as $ x \cos 30^0 - y \cos 30^0 = 5$. So, how do I choose the signs while converting this way?

I understand that there are simpler alternatives to transform the equation from general form to normal form, but I'd like to know how to do it by this method as well.

Further, how do I choose which the angle $ \omega $ if two angles satisfy the expressions obtained. For example, if we consider the equation $ y - 2 = 0$, then $ p = \pm 2 $, $ \cos \omega = 0 $ and $ \sin \omega = \pm 1 $. In this case, we can see that both the angles $ 90^0 $ and $ 270^0 $ satisfy the expressions. (At 90 degrees, cos is 0 and sin is 1, while at 270, cos is 0 and sin is -1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the entire equation by $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$. You get (after moving the free term to the other side): $$x\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}+y\frac B{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=-\frac C{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$
So if $\cos\theta=\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$, you need to keep the same sign for $\sin\theta$, and choose the opposite sign for $p$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't completely understand. Would you mind explaining this for an example? Let's say, we have $ x - \sqrt{3} y+ 8 = 0 $. After dividing by $ \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} $ and moving the free term, we have, $ \frac x2 - y \frac { \sqrt{3}}{2} = - \frac 82 $. The cos term is positive; so, should I make the sin term positive as well? And we should make the p term positive?

Comment: Sorry, I could have been a little clearer. No. Keep $\cos\omega=1/2$, $\sin\omega=-\sqrt 3/2$, and $p=-4$. Alternatively, you can switch sign for all of them: $\cos\omega =-1/2$, $\sin\omega=\sqrt 3/2$, and $p=4$. The meaning of this change can be understood as following: In the first case, you have an angle in the second quadrant, and then a negative displacement. That is equivalent to going in exactly opposite direction, with a positive displacement.